# How to create an SDK-style .NET Framework project in VS?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, csproj

Is it possible to create an `SDK-style` `.NET Framework` project in Visual Studio (to be more specific I use the latest VS2019)? Or does it still require manual manipulations?

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

I'm interested in creating a new project, not in migrating existing project from old `.csproj` file style to the new `.csproj` `SDK-style`.
I've already edited `.csproj` files manually many times but it's super inconvenient.

Comment: All .NET Core and .NET Standard projects use the new project format. What are you trying to do? Create a .NET Framework project with the new format?

Comment: Sure, just create a new .NET Standard / .NET Core project, and change the `<TargetFramework>`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I have to work with .net framework. And it's possible to use sdk style projects in .net framework. I wanted to know how to create such projects with VS. Now I have to edit csproj file manually

Comment: @canton7 so it seems like forcing developers use .net core/standard projects and not to use .net framework projects

Comment: @isxaker I think it's just that there isn't a template for .NET Framework + SDK-style, but you can very easily use the .NET Core / Standard + SDK-Style template, and change a couple of characters to set the target to net48 or whatever

Comment: @canton7 so it still requires manual manipulations )

Comment: Yeah, but if you're using an SDK-style project you're going to be manually manipulating the csproj *anyway* (and VS makes this easy with SDK-style projects). Chances are that the template isn't using the right version of netstandard / netcoreapp, so you're going to be changing it regardless. It's just you'll change it from e.g. netstandard2.1 to net48, instead of e.g. netstandard2.1 to netstandard2.0

Answer (score 42, accepted):

We have to create a sdk-style .net framework project manually. By setting the `TargetFramework` to *(for example)* `net472`.

You can refer to the following steps to make it.

First, we need to create a Class Library (.NET Standard) project.

Second, we need to modify the csproj file.

The initial file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

You can edit it to:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Finally, you can get a sdk-style .net framework project.

[image]

Comment: and in case i want to "upgrade" an existing (old) csproj file where i have all the includes... do I need to add them manually, too?

Comment: If you want to "upgrade" an existing .NET-Framework project to use the SDK style project format but still target .NET Framework you can use the dotnet-upgrade-assistant tool and exit after the "convert project to sdk style" step. See: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/upgrade-assistant

Comment: I didn't even realize this was possible.  Is there any reason why VS can't do this by default?  Has this changed?

Comment: Unchanged at least on Visual Studio 2019.  I used Tobias Hoefer's suggestion and worked good for me on four .net 4.0 projects, one of them WPF. WPF project did have one minor issue. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75316507/623561).  I did migrate from packages.config to PackageReference (right click project to do this) before doing this.

Comment: Exiting after the "convert project to sdk style" step does not seem to exist anymore in `upgrade-assistant`.

Comment: The old `upgrade-assistant` version (which is able to cancel after SDK style migration was done) can be installed with `dotnet tool install --global upgrade-assistant --version 0.4.421302`.

Comment: The new (0.5.261.51392) version of the upgrade-assistant has a special section specifically for sdk type upgrades so no need to "exit early" anymore.  Just select "Upgrade project features"

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to the comments on the previous answer which pointed to `upgrade-assistant`. Here are the commands I used:

Install [the tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-install):

```
$ dotnet tool install -g upgrade-assistant
```

Then either [run interactively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#upgrade-with-the-cli-tool) and select "Upgrade project features > Convert project to SDK style (feature.sdkstyle)":

```
upgrade-assistant upgrade
```

Or do this in one-shot on the cli like this:

```
upgrade-assistant upgrade MyProj/MyProj.csproj -o feature.sdkstyle
```

Answer (score 0):

Easyest way for do that - just use **template for .Net Core**
[image]

choose any framework.

[image]

When VS generate for you file *.csproj, open it by click mouse

[image]

delete 2 lines      `<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings> <Nullable>enable</Nullable>`

and change TargetFramework to **net48** (in case you use NetFramework 4.8)
[image]