# WinFoms Designer in VS2019 won't open newly created form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a simple C# project (SDK style, targetting .NET Framework 4.8). When I right click my project and add a new WinForm, the designer refuses to open the form. It just shows this error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The callstack that is shown below the error message does not help (me) at all:

```
at System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder.Create(IDictionary resourceList, String baseName, String generatedCodeNamespace, String resourcesNamespace, CodeDomProvider codeProvider, Boolean internalClass, String[]& unmatchable)
at System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder.Create(IDictionary resourceList, String baseName, String generatedCodeNamespace, CodeDomProvider codeProvider, Boolean internalClass, String[]& unmatchable)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObject.BuildType()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObject.GetObjectType()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalType.get_ObjectType()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObject.get_Children()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObjectProvider.CreateGlobalObjectsForItem(ProjectItem item, GlobalObjectCollection oldObjects, GlobalObjectCollection newObjects, ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObjectProvider.CreateGlobalObjectsForItem(ProjectItem item, GlobalObjectCollection oldObjects, GlobalObjectCollection newObjects, ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObjectProvider.CreateGlobalObjectsForItem(ProjectItem item, GlobalObjectCollection oldObjects, GlobalObjectCollection newObjects, ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObjectProvider.CreateGlobalObjects(Project project)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.ResXGlobalObjectProvider.GetGlobalObjectsCore(Project project, Type baseType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalObjectProvider.GetGlobalObjects(Project project, Type baseType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalObjectService.GetGlobalObjects(Type baseType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetTypeFromGlobalObjects(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.GetRuntimeType(String typeName)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.GetType(String typeName)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.GetType(String typeName)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.GetType(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, Dictionary`2 names)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.FillStatementTable(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, IDictionary table, Dictionary`2 names, CodeStatementCollection statements, String className)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

Has anyone seen this kind of behavior?
Is there any way to make the designer load the WinForm?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an SDK-style .NET Framework project in VS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63055430/how-to-create-an-sdk-style-net-framework-project-in-vs)

Comment: You have to specify how and when you changed the default Project style of a .Net Framework WinForms Project to an SDK-style Project. Is there a specific reason why you did that with VS 2019? Was it an existing default Project, with `EmbeddedResource` groups already included?

Comment: Do you need to create an sdk-style .net project?

Comment: @user9938 No, that does not help.

Comment: @Jimi I recently converted the project to SDK style. VS2019 is the latest version of VS, so that's what I used. It was an existing project that included several resources.

Comment: @Lynn-MSFT I was asked to convert it to SDK style since that seems to be the more modern format. It also offers several advantages (e.g. a cleaner .csproj file structure, easier Nuget packaging etc.).

Comment: The *latest* version is [Visual Studio 2022](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/), which provides a new interface to handle the Project's configuration, VS 2019 doesn't have one. The `<ItemGroup>` logic that stores basic resources is slightly different (different groupings), so are some of the keywords used (e.g., `<Compile Update ...>` / `<None Update...>` vs. `<Compile Include ...>` / `<None Include...>`) etc. -- You cannot just replace the main, old style, `<PropertyGroup>` with the new one and leave the rest as it is